Magento 2 : How can I get simple product id on category page for configurable product
We have a configurable product on the front end
How can I get the final simple product ID on the product list page?
Does anyone have any idea how to get it?

Have you given the selection of Size and Colour on category Page?

Can you provide me with the code on how can I get the product ID on the product list page for configurable products? @DhirenVasoya
as I have got the product id for PDP page from this code so how can I do the same for product list page
$(".product-options-wrapper .swatch-opt").click(function() {
var selProId = $('[data-role=swatch-options]').data('mage-SwatchRenderer').getProduct();

The code depend on the structure which apply on caetgory page, that why I ask how you given selection on category page?

I have configurable products which I have size and color options on the PLP page @Dhiren Vasoya

That I know, how you provided those options on Category page, because based on that selection you need to get Simple Product Id.

You need to provide swatch/attribute selection on the product cards on the listing page.
Once you select any options, you will find the selected product id using the below syntax.
jQuery("input[name=selected_configurable_option]").val()


var selProId = $('[data-role="swatch-option-"]').data('mage-SwatchRenderer').getProduct();
how we can give product id dynamically as in data-role like this swatch-option-2040 for product list page

Hi @UrmiKothari, not exactly getting it. Could you please elaborate? Or reach out to me at magento@tridhyatech.com.

Hello @Magento TridhyaTech
The issue is resolved now from this way I get the product id in plp page for configurable product
        var productId = $(this).attr('id').replace('product-item-info_', '');
        var selProId = $('[data-role="swatch-option-' + productId + '"]').data('mage-SwatchRenderer').getProduct();

